# Erlang emakefile explain

Tags: erlang

I have an [Emakefile](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html) that looks like:

```
%% --
%%
%% --

{'/Users/user/projects/custom_test/trunk/*', 
 [debug_info, 
  {outdir, "/Users/user/projects/custom_test/trunk/ebin"},  
  {i, "/Users/user/projects/custom_test/trunk/include/."}
 ]
}.
```

1. What is an explanation in layman's terms for what each item does in the list?
2. How do I run the emakefile so that I am able to compile it?
3. After compilation, how do I run that generated [BEAM](http://www.cs-lab.org/historical_beam_instruction_set.html#0%20Introduction) file?

Answer (score 14):

1/    `{"source files globbed", Options}`

Here the options are :

- `debug_info` add debug info for the debugger
- `{outdir, "/Users/user/projects/custom_test/trunk/ebin"}` where should the output be written (the .beam files)
- `{i, "/Users/user/projects/custom_test/trunk/include/."}` where to find the `.hrl` header files.

2/ `erl -make`

3/ `erl -pa /Users/user/projects/custom_test/trunk/ebin` starts a shell.

Find the module serving as an entry point in your application and call the functions :
 `module:start().`

You can also run the code non interactively :

`erl -noinput -noshell -pa /Users/user/projects/custom_test/trunk/ebin -s module start`

Comment: no need to run c(module). ?   how to find out entry point for app?

Comment: no, erl -make does that for you.

The entry point : read the code, find an aptly named function, I can't help you here.

Comment: may i know how to call the start function in this erl file http://www.copypastecode.com/13830/   it has 2 arguments

Comment: You should have an .app file in the ebin folder.
It means it's an OTP app, and it can be started with :
application:start(weazard).

In the console.
Now I can recommend reading the documentation.

Comment: 1.i try to run the weazard.app but it tell me 'classic environment no longer supported' . 2.by the way how to generate the weazard.app? it doesnt generated by erl -make . 3 weazard.app is a plaintext macos executable file?  4. how to run wezard.app , double click ?

Answer (score 4):

1. For the Emakefile synax visit the [man page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html)
2. In the directory where the Emakefile is run `erl -make` to compile using the Emakefile
3. Simplest way to run would be to simply start an erlang shell in the same directory as the beam files with the command `erl`. Then run the code with `module_name:function_name().` (including the dot).

Comment: may i know how to call the start function in this erl file http://www.copypastecode.com/13830/   it has 2 arguments